# Writing to a single file from multiple threads in ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I am trying to write to a single file from multiple threads. The problem I'm running into is that I don't see anything being written to the file until the program exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `file.flush` to write it out. You can also set `file.sync = true` to have it flush automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the sync method on your io object? It is possible that either ruby or the underlying o/s are buffering the file output.

Check out the refences on buffering and syncing within the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002262)